# Can't use preventDefault() with if, else

Tags: javascript, jquery, preventdefault

`$.get` in the code below returns a boolean value in JSON format named `data`. But whether the value of `data` is false or true `preventDefault()` prevents the submission of the form anyway.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#username").blur(function() {
    let username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    
    $.get("/check", {
      username_value: username
    }, function(data) {
      alert(data);
      
      $("#submit").click(function(e) {
        if (data) {
          e.preventDefault();
        } else if (!data) {
          e.submit();
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

And this is the /check part

```
@app.route("/check", methods=["GET"])
def check():
    """Return true if username available, else false, in JSON format"""
    get_username = request.args.get("username_value")

    users = db.execute("SELECT username FROM users")

    lenght = len(get_username)
    i = 0
    for user in users:
        if get_username == users[i]["username"] or not lenght > 1:
            return jsonify(True)
        i += 1

    return jsonify(False)
```

I am very new at coding business btw. Thanks for help.

Comment: What does `alert(data)` look like? I'm betting it's a string or something instead of a boolean

Comment: `data` will be a string, so it will always coerce to a truthy value unless its empty, however you're returning `'true'` or `'false'` so that will not be the case. I would strongly suggest you return a structured data format, such as JSON, to avoid this problem and use a boolean for the value. In addition `e.submit()` will cause an error as the event has no `submit` method. The `else` can be removed entirely.

Comment: I thougt data part was working because when I cahange `e.preventDefault();` and `e.submit();` with `alert(data);` it shows the message that I want to see: true or false

Comment: Right, but they will be strings, not booleans, and type coercion will mean that both `'true'` and `'false'` = `true`. This is why using `alert()` for debugging is not good practice. Use `console.log()` instead, and use a boolean value in a structured type for the response from your AJAX call.

Comment: It turns out the `data` was a boolean all the time. Just checked it with `typeof` and it returned boolean as result. Any other ideas? Thanks for the advices btw :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem by replacing the `$.get` with `$.ajax`. I guess the problem was about the fact that `$.get` only works async. So I used `$.ajax`'s async paramater at false. Then it worked just as I want.

Last version of the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
          $('#form').submit(function(e){
              let username = document.getElementById("username").value;
              let password = document.getElementById("password").value;
              let confirmation = document.getElementById("confirmation").value;
              var boolean_data;
              $.ajax({url: "/check?username=" + username, type: 'get', async: false, success: function(data){boolean_data=data;}});

              if(!boolean_data) {
                alert("\"" + username + "\"" + " username is already taken.");
                e.preventDefault();
              }
              else if(!password || !confirmation) {
                  alert("Pls povide a password and confrim it");
                  e.preventDefault();
              }
              else if(password != confirmation) {
                  alert("Passwords don't match");
                  e.preventDefault();
              }

          });
      });
```

Thanks to everyone who commented and answered my question.

Comment: Setting async:false on a get request will lock up the browser until the request completes. You probably don't want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try change to capture the event from form ID instead of button this way:

```
$("#form").submit(function (e) {
  if (!data) {
    e.preventDefault();    
  } else {
    e.submit();
  }
});
```

**e.submit() must be used in event from a submited form.**

Make sure data is boolean type. and don't forget change the selector to your form ID.

Comment: I am pretty sure the `data` is boolean because I checked it with `typeof` and thanks to you I changed the event from form ID to the form tag's id but that didn't work too. Thank for your advice tho.